# Direct only mobile devices not tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, device-detection

I have this line of code which detects all touch devices:

```
<script>if( 'ontouchstart' in window ) window.location = 'mobile.html';</script>
```

I just want modify it so that it ONLY targets touch enabled mobile devices but also excludes tablet devices. How do I do this without being too specific?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting to redirect a user to your mobile site you would use this:

```
if (screen.width <= 768) {
        window.location = "mobile.html";
    }
```

If you want to find out if its touch screen and less than 768px I think you could use this:

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

var viewport = $(window).width()

if (is_touch_device == true && viewport < 768) {

   (Code goes here)

}
```